# Automatically copy podcasts onto ipod

Tags: sync, banshee, ipod, rhythmbox

I'd like to be able to plug my 5th gen iPod nano into my Ubuntu 10.04 box and have it sync podcasts. I'd like newly downloaded podcasts to be copied onto the iPod, and played podcasts to be removed from the iPod.

I've tried syncing with:

- **Rhythmbox** detects the iPod when it's plugged in, but doesn't sync podcasts to it.
- **Banshee** doesn't detect the iPod [unless I kill Nautilus](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/ipod-doesnt-work-karmic.html). It also doesn't sync podcasts without intervention.
- **gPodder** doesn't seem to detect the iPod. It will sync, but only if I tell it to. And it marks podcasts as unheard. The `gpo sync` commandline app has the same problem.
- **gtkpod** doesn't detect the iPod. It will sync with intervention, but it syncs podcasts as songs.

This feels like a problem that someone else would have encountered by now. How do I get my Ubuntu box to sync podcasts with my iPod?

Comment: This question is abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please flag explaining why and the moderators will re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that you couldn't get it working with gPodder. I had this working with Ubuntu 10.04 but with an iPod 30GB video (a generation before yours?). I did have to fiddle a bit to make it work, but once working it was pretty much automatic.

Have you tried a newer version of gpodder than we have in Ubuntu?

The gpodder authors ppa has 2.7, Ubuntu Lucid has 2.2

https://launchpad.net/~thp/+archive/gpodder

Comment: Yeah, I tried 2.7. It doesn't look as snazzy as 2.2 but fails in the same way.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about getting gpodder to behave properly?

Comment: Sadly not, I no longer use it.

Answer (score 0):

http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/ -- formally know as ipodder, now called juice provides the functionality your looking for.

:)

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

I'm still interested in seeing a solution involving an app in a ppa. =)

Comment: Good luck let me know how it goes.

Comment: No luck. Since there's no linux distribution of Juicereceiver, I grabbed the latest iPodder (from '05). That fails to start complaining of errors using wx widgets - it appears that the packages it depended on are no longer available. 

I also tried IcePodder (recommended on the Juicereceiver site), but that's a fail too: it also has a dependency that's no longer available.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: To clarify what @MartinOwens-doctormo- has said: this answer would be better if it included information on how to install juicereceiver and also on how to use it to perform this particular task. (Screenshots to go along with the explanatory text could be helpful too.)

Answer (score -1):

You cant really "sync" but you can copy,paste and move things to-and from the iPod. What you can do is set up a cron job to sync hourly. You would need to set up a script to see where the mount point of the iPod is and to copy to the appropriate folder.

Comment: I'd really like to do this without resorting to writing my own scripts. `cron` doesn't feel like something an "os for human beings" should make its users touch.